# How to compare if, 2 separate Objects/Array have one same element and concat 2 objects into one array, if there is matching element? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a promise.all that returns 2 objects. The common element in these 2 seperate objects is `room`. 
I want both object to be in 1 array, and if the room matches, I would like to concat the objects.

```js
const urls = ['/room/*/userconfig', '/room/*/observation/latest'];
let requests = urls.map(url => axios.get(url)); 

Promise.all(requests)
  .then(res => {
        let patientObjArray = Object.values(res[0].data);
        let patientObservationsArray = Object.values(res[1].data);
  })


const patientObjArray = [
  {
    room: "room18",
    patient: "91911671-302b-47b5-a24d-d2a1fea548d6",
    hospitalNumber: "12"
  },
  {
    room: "room19",
    patient: "b793bbba-b2bb-4995-9247-bb4d4f2be65a",
    hospitalNumber: "13"
  },
  {
    room: "room20",
    patient: "a8e8efa1-ea00-4d32-b4b2-58727200b9b0",
    hospitalNumber: "14"
  },
  {
    room: "room21",
    patient: "asdadddaddada-b4badasd2-7272a00qb9b0",
    hospitalNumber: "15"
  }
];

// patientObservationsArray is data related to patientObjArray.room

const patientObservationsArray = [
  {
    observation: {
      room: "room18",
      timestamp: "10:00",
      patient: "91911671-302b-47b5-a24d-d2a1fea548d6"
    },
    comment: { value: "Ok" }
  },
  {
    observation: {
      room: "room19",
      timestamp: "11:00",
      patient: "b793bbba-b2bb-4995-9247-bb4d4f2be65a"
    },
    comment: { value: "Good" }
  },
  {
    observation: {
      room: "room20",
      timestamp: "12:00",
      patient: "a8e8efa1-ea00-4d32-b4b2-58727200b9b0"
    },
    comment: { value: "bad" }
  }
];
```

**expected output**

```
const combinedArray = [
  {
    room: "room18",
    patient: "91911671-302b-47b5-a24d-d2a1fea548d6",
    hospitalNumber: "12",
    timestamp: "10:00",
    comment: "Ok"
  },
  {
    room: "room19",
    patient: "b793bbba-b2bb-4995-9247-bb4d4f2be65a",
    hospitalNumber: "13",
    timestamp: "11:00",
    comment: "Good"
  },
  {
    room: "room20",
    patient: "a8e8efa1-ea00-4d32-b4b2-58727200b9b0",
    hospitalNumber: "14",
    timestamp: "12:00",
    comment: "Bad"
  },
  {
    room: "room21",
    patient: "asdadddaddada-b4badasd2-7272a00qb9b0",
    hospitalNumber: "15"
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. Please try this code.

```js
const mergedArray = patientObjArray.map(obj => {
    const matched = patientObservationsArray.find(obs => obs.observation.room === obj.room);
    if (!!matched) {
        return { ...obj, ...matched.observation, comment: matched.comment.value };
    } else {
        return obj;
    }
});

console.log(mergedArray);
```

Comment: Hi did you mean to use double `!!`matched?

Comment: !! returns always boolean value. It doesn't affect the result of the above code(automatically converted to boolean), but that is a more clear code. In certain cases(like react.js app), !! is needed.

Comment: doesn if(matched) check work because it is boolean?

Answer (score 0):

You can first flatten your `patientObservationsArray`, then merge it with your `patientObjArray` and finally use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to merge your array.

There are probably better ways of doing this, feel free to give me suggestions. This should solve your problem.

```js
const patientObjArray = [
  {
    room: "room18",
    patient: "91911671-302b-47b5-a24d-d2a1fea548d6",
    hospitalNumber: "12"
  },
  {
    room: "room19",
    patient: "b793bbba-b2bb-4995-9247-bb4d4f2be65a",
    hospitalNumber: "13"
  },
  {
    room: "room20",
    patient: "a8e8efa1-ea00-4d32-b4b2-58727200b9b0",
    hospitalNumber: "14"
  },
  {
    room: "room21",
    patient: "asdadddaddada-b4badasd2-7272a00qb9b0",
    hospitalNumber: "15"
  }
];

const patientObservationsArray = [
  {
    observation: {
      room: "room18",
      timestamp: "10:00",
      patient: "91911671-302b-47b5-a24d-d2a1fea548d6"
    },
    comment: { value: "Ok" }
  },
  {
    observation: {
      room: "room19",
      timestamp: "11:00",
      patient: "b793bbba-b2bb-4995-9247-bb4d4f2be65a"
    },
    comment: { value: "Good" }
  },
  {
    observation: {
      room: "room20",
      timestamp: "12:00",
      patient: "a8e8efa1-ea00-4d32-b4b2-58727200b9b0"
    },
    comment: { value: "bad" }
  }
];

const combinedArray = patientObservationsArray
  // flatten your patientObservationsArray
  .map(item => ({ ...item.observation, ...item.comment }))
  // concat to your patientObjArray
  .concat(patientObjArray)
  // use reduce method to merge your array
  .reduce((res, item) => {
    const { room } = item;
    const index = res.findIndex(i => i.room === room);
    if (index > -1) {
      // merge object if already exists
      res[index] = { ...res[index], ...item };
    } else {
      // else push into your array
      res.push(item);
    }
    return res;
  }, []);

console.log(combinedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a playcode plunkr for my suggestion: https://playcode.io/473861?tabs=script.js,preview,console

We simply loop through the first array, run every object through a matching function against the second array and add the objects into a new array. If a match is found the required fields are added.

I would suggest keeping the object structure similar just to make using the objects in new data easier.